# When running pip install channels I get the following this error

Tags: python, django, pip, django-channels

When running `pip install channels` I get the following error.
ImportError: No module named pathlib.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'E:\Users\S.Mary\Documents\WebProject1\chatty_env\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\s3c67~1.mar\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-spnlrp\\async-timeout\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\s3c67~1.mar\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-spnlrp\\async-timeout\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\s3c67~1.mar\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-yzixua'
             cwd: c:\users\s3c67~1.mar\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-spnlrp\async-timeout\
        Complete output (5 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "c:\users\s3c67~1.mar\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-spnlrp\async-timeout\setup.py", line 1, in <module>
            import pathlib
        ImportError: No module named pathlib
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Run on command line:

```
pip install pathlib
```

or on Linux

```
sudo pip install pathlib
```

Comment: @Mary Нет проблем!

Comment: But when running pip install channels_redis I get the following same error

Comment: Does it say `No module named pathlib` in error?

Comment: "RuntimeError: aioredis doesn't support Python version prior 3.5"

Comment: @Mary Looks like you've ran into a different issue now

Comment: @Mary please check the CPython tested version here, Check and Show what version you're using? https://pypi.org/project/aioredis/

Comment: @user:7735255 версия 2.7.18. До более новой версии не обновляется

Answer (score 0):

python is complaining that it cannot find the module named pathlib. you may add to your library using pip or pip3 according to your python version.

or even pathlib2 and change your code accordingly.
https://pypi.org/project/pathlib/

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "c:\users\s3c67~1.mar\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-spnlrp\async-timeout\setup.py", line 1, in import pathlib ImportError: **No module named pathlib** ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.